# Python - How to insert '*' into a string after every nth character

Tags: python, string, append

I'm currently stuck on this question that takes 2 arguments (string, and an int, n) and it should return a new string where every nth character (from 0) is followed by an '*'.

I've found similar questions on stack overflow but the answers include more advanced coding functions that I don't know how to use (like range(), emurate etc) as I just started out coding.

What the code supposed to do:

```
>>> string_chunks("Once upon a time, in a land far, far away", 5)
'O*nce u*pon a* time*, in *a lan*d far*, far* away*'
```

My code so far only prints out every 5th character from the string:

```
def string_chunks(string, x):
    new = ''
    for ch in string[::x]:
        new += ch 
    return new

>>>'Ouae nrry'
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use str.find()/str.split() in my code. It would be a great help if someone can help me improve or guide me. Thanks!

Comment: In your example for the way the code works, the first * is after 1 character when it should be after 5. Is that supposed to be the correct behavior?

Comment: @pinkfluffyunicorn I thought about it as well but I think it's correct. In other questions on stack overflow the output of their code also has * after 1 character. Also, this question is from a workbook so it should be right! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example seems incorrecnt. `nth` position meaning each index is a multiple of `n`.

But, if your phrasing is wrong, you can always shift `n` or `cnt` to make sure it matches your desired output.

You are not adding any starts in your function, just check if the position is a multiple of x, if `yes` then add a `*`.

```
def string_chunks(string, x):
    new = ''
    cnt = 0
    for ch in string:
        if cnt%x==0 and cnt!=0: # checking if cnt is a multiple of x and not 0, we don't want to put star at index 0
            new += '*'
        cnt += 1
        new += ch
    return new
string_chunks("Once upon a time, in a land far, far away", 5)
```

Out:
`'Once *upon *a tim*e, in* a la*nd fa*r, fa*r awa*y'`

Comment: Hi! Looking through your code I noticed this "if cnt%x==0:" and I was wondering what this does to the code?

Comment: It's a modulo operator, it cheks if cnt is a multiple of x or not. For example, if x = 5, then, 10%5 = 0, 11%5 = 1. It just gives a remainder in simple sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_asterisk_every(string, n):
    # Create a list to hold the characters in the new string we'll be creating.
    with_asterisks = []

    # Keep track of how many characters we've passed since the last asterisk was added.
    characters_scanned = 0

    # Iterate through each character of the input string and add each character of the input string to with_asterisks.
    # Once we scan n characters, we'll add an asterisk and restart the counter.
    for character in string:
        if characters_scanned == n:
            with_asterisks.append('*')
            characters_scanned = 0
        characters_scanned += 1
        with_asterisks.append(character)

    # Create the output string from our character list.
    return ''.join(with_asterisks)

print(add_asterisk_every("Once upon a time, in a land far, far away", 5))
```

Which produces:

```
Once *upon *a tim*e, in* a la*nd fa*r, fa*r awa*y
```